# Using RSpec shared example groups with belongs_to associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

In a Rails project (rails 5.2.2, ruby 2.4.1) I have 2 resources defined, one named "groups" and one named "products".  Product objects have a belongs_to relationship with a Group.  I wanted to created an rspec shared example group which can test both resources, but I'm having some trouble with the "create" and "update" actions for "products".

I wanted to setup a shared set of example groups which take a hash used to create a new record as a parameter.  The example group could then be called within both the "groups_spec.rb" and the "products_spec.rb".  I have fixtures for both "groups" and "products.  The following is a code example for the "requests/products_spec.rb" which calls the shared examples:

```
RSpec.describe "Products", type: :request do
   fixtures :groups, :products
   it_should_behave_like("modify data checks",
         Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.api_products_path,
         Product,
         { product: {
            name: "New Product",
            description: "Test product to add or modify",
            group_id: Group.first.id,
            label: "NP"
         } })
   end
end
```

The problem with products is that the new product data requires a group_id which must be valid inside the context of the example group, but I have to be able to retrieve the group_id from outside the example group in order to pass it in.

I'm guessing the real answer is to reorganize how the example group is structured, so I'll take a recommendation on how to restructure the shared example group.  Of course, if I'm simply just doing something wrong here, I'll take that answer too.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good place to use shared example groups.  I don't see Product and Group sharing much functionality. Shared example groups are more for scenarios such as having Ingredient and Packaging.  Since both can be purchased, you can DRY out your code and make it more easily maintainable with `it_should_behave_like :it_is_purchasable` or `a_purchasable_item`.  This is of course just my opinion, and I wanted to put it out there for discussion.

Comment: We do use shared example groups across a variety of models/controllers. As long as you limit the sharing to what's actually shared I haven't run into any issues with readability/refactorability. When you start throwing conditionals into your shared example, looking at args, etc. then it gets crazy. I posted an example as an answer (but I'm not sure if it addresses what you're looking for). Please feel free to ask any questions for clarification

Comment: @Tom I'm trying to use shared example groups for a lot of the really basic test that probably apply to any fully implemented resource.  "Does #index return all my fixture defined records?", "Does #create actually create a new record?", etc.  Then use non-shared examples to test the more specific functionality.  I just think it should be possible to setup a basic test suite of shared examples that I can attach to any new resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a `let` inside of the `it_behaves_like` block like below:

```
RSpec.describe "Products", type: :request do
  fixtures :groups, :products

  # This shared example probably lives in another file, which is fine
  # I don't usually pass in args, instead using everything via `let`
  shared_example 'modify_data_checks' do
    # you have access to all your variables via let inside here
    before do
      visit(path)
    end

    expect(model).to be_a(Product)
    expect(group_id).to eq(1)
  end

  it_behaves_like 'modify_data_checks' do
    let(:path) { Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.api_products_path }
    let(:model) { Product }
    let(:group_id) { Group.first.id }
    let(:params) { 
      product: {
        name: "New Product",
        description: "Test product to add or modify",
        group_id: group_id,
        label: "NP"
      }
    }
  end
end
```

You should be able to pass data around relatively cleanly like this. We're using a pattern similar to this to test polymorphic relationships using shared examples.

Comment: Your response is making me cry (out of joy).  I thought for sure the only answer was restructure your whole test suite.  Also, converting to this pattern is relatively painless.  Thanks!!!